# apxproof adds an aditional page for appendix ! How can I stop this?

Tags: page-breaking, appendix

I am trying to make sure that there is no page breaking when I add an appendix using the `apxproof` package.
But I am not sure How to go about it ?

```
\documentclass[runningheads]{llncs}
\usepackage{apxproof}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
            A=B
\end{theorem}
\begin{toappendix}
\begin{proof}
The proof is left as an exercise
\end{proof}
\end{toappendix}
\end{document}
```

This adds two pages in my document, whereas I would like to have no page break for appendix. How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The package `apxproof` collects the stuff and inserts it with a hook

```
\AtEndDocument{
   \appendixprelim
   \appendix
   % [other stuff]
}
```

The macro `\appendixprelim`, whose original definition reads

```
\newcommand{\appendixprelim}{\clearpage\onecolumn}
```

is designed precisely to customize what happens. For example

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{apxproof}
\newtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}
\renewcommand*{\appendixprelim}{}

\begin{document}
\begin{theorem}
            A=B
\end{theorem}
\begin{toappendix}
\begin{proof}
The proof is left as an exercise
\end{proof}
\end{toappendix}
Other text.
\end{document}
```

[image]

(I don't have your class so I cannot say exactly how the output will look like.)

Comment: '+1' works like a charm!